# Having Trouble Using Session in Rails undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a devise registration controller here

```
class Students::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/events/new'
  end 

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path(resource)
    '/events/new'
  end 

  def brand
    brand ||= Brand.find(params[:brand]) 
    session[:brand] = Brand.find(params[:brand]) #not working 
  end 
  helper_method :brand 
end
```

after somebody sign up it will send them to events/new page

Before someone goes to the sign up page, they will have to go through a brands page

```
=link_to t('slide2.apply_here'), new_student_registration_path(:brand => brand.id),class: "button-component", style: "font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 50px;"
```

please note that the brand id is getting passed through the link_to as a params to the registration controller. I have the brand method to capture the brand id, find the brand and use it on the view in the sign up page.

I want to do the same thing for events/new hence storing the Brand in the session.

I keep on getting undefined local variable or method brand.

I have this in events new view

```
%h3=brand.name
```

I know session should be short, it should just be

```
session[:brand] = params[:brand]
```

but then I am getting my signup page undefined now, its messing up my helper method.

updated

I just dropped this in my events new view

```
.row
  .span4
    .accordion#picture_accordion.left
    =image_tag brand.image_url
    %h3=brand.name
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
brand ||= Brand.find(params[:brand])
```

this is like saying

```
brand = brand || Brand.find(params[:brand])
```

If `brand` hasn't been defined at this point you will get an "undefined local variable or method" error.

If you change it to an instance variable, `@brand`, it should work, since undefined instance variables evaluate to nil.

EDIT - this is my 'current_user' method, which sounds comparable.

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= (session[:user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]))
end
```

what's happening here is that the first time `current_user` is called, it loads the current user using session[:user_id] and saves it in an instance variable called @current_user.  The next time `current_user` is called, in the same action, it will just use the object it has saved into the instance variable, and not load it out of the database again.

Note that in this system the controller and view code which wants to know who the current user is should always call `current_user`, **not** `@current_user`.  @current_user is just used by the `current_user` method to save the value for the duration of the page render.

Comment: I need more clarification, so is my session code ok if I change it to `@brand` am I accessing the session correctly in my view?

Comment: Are you saving the brand_id in the students table?    See my edit.